# Do I need a firewall on a small device with only one port open

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, raspberry-pi

I plan to build a Raspberry Pi serving only one purpose.

- There is only one port open
- Everyone should be able to connect to this port
- The application listening on this port does not have root privileges
- It does not route. I.e. there are no other PCs reachable via this Raspberry Pi
- No outbound connections. I.e. the Raspberry Pi will not connect actively to another PC
- I will do port scans to assert that there are no other ports open

So, do I need a firewall, running on this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would still set-up the (of course existing) netfilter firewall - if you are on a public network.

Namely, I would block any other traffic types like ICMP etc. Moreover, most port/system scanners detect system types by all kinds of error response ("port unreachable") etc, so you definitively decrease the attacking surface; your goal is to leak as few information about your system as possible.

Moreover, ICMP responses ("ping") will get returned if you do not actively block them. And I think you don't want this either (at least I would).

Comment: Good point, especially considering the telltale error responses.

Answer (score -1):

The firewall job is done by netfilter/iptables on linux

So a firewall simply results in an iptables configuration dropping all incoming tcp connections. (And maybe blocking outgoing connections.)

I personally would not create such a firewall configuration.
It's not neccessary if you know that you only have a single server application running.

Run

```
netstat -ltw
```

to see if you only have one application listening to tcp connections. Maybe there are some pre-installed server applications you want to eliminate.

```
-l means listen
-t means tcp
-w means raw (will show the ping server)
```

You should also check your bind ip address. You might only want to accept clients in the same LAN and ignore clients from the internet (yes, internet).

Comment: May I ask why my answer was downvoted?